# How to speed up program that updates many UI items periodically?

Tags: java, android

I created a small application where I have a list of products and for each of the product I have an expiry time. If the user chooses to like a certain product(showTimerPost), the expiry time of the product will increase lets say 5 second. I tried it with a handler and it actually worked but my app started to run really slow maybe because it was changing the UI every second. I am really stuck with this problem for 1 month. Help will be appreciated.

```
package com.blueflair.incre;


import com.blueflair.incre.app.AppController;
import com.blueflair.incre.data.FeedItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;


public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    LocalUserData userLocalStore;
    long postExpiry;
    String timerFormat;
    private int defaultPostIncrementation = 900000;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    boolean favourite;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private long timeDiff;
    private final List<ViewHolder> lstHolders;
    private int avatarSize;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (final ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                holder.showTimerPost.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        currentTime--;
                        holder.showTimerPost.setText(String.valueOf(holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime)));
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    };


    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        userLocalStore = new LocalUserData(activity);
        final User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
        postExpiry = item.getPostExpiry();
        avatarSize = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.feed_avater_size);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userFeedName);
        holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        holder.statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);

        holder.profilePic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        holder.profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle args= new Bundle();
                args.putInt("userId", item.getUserId());
                Fragment profileViewFragment = new ProfileViewFragment();
                profileViewFragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((MainActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_done, R.anim.slide_out_send);
                ft.replace(R.id.container_body, profileViewFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        holder.feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        String username = "@"+item.getUserName();
        holder.name.setText(username);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        synchronized ( lstHolders) {
            lstHolders.add(holder);
        }
        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeCreated()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        holder.timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
        holder.showTimerPost = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.showPostTimer);
        handler.post(timerRunnable);
        holder.showTimerPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setIncrementToExpiry(50000);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getPostMessage())) {
            holder.statusMsg.setText(item.getPostMessage());
            holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Feed image
        if (item.getUserImage() != null) {
            holder.feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getUserImage(), imageLoader);
            holder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            holder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        //Setting the timer adapter for the post and their respective contents
        holder.setData(item);
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        FeedItem item;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView timestamp;
        public TextView statusMsg;
        public ImageView profilePic;
        public FeedImageView feedImageView;
        public Button showTimerPost;

        public void setData(FeedItem item) {
            this.item = item;
            updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public String updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {

            timeDiff = (item.getPostExpiry()+400000000) - currentTime;
            if (timeDiff > 0) {

                timerFormat = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff)));

                showTimerPost.setText(timerFormat);
                return timerFormat;
            } else {
                //Delete feed items when post is expired
                showTimerPost.setText("Expired!");//only to explimify
            }
            return timerFormat;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I will give you the link of what I did with my app in a similar way but without incrementation.

Comment: Ok no problem. I will give you the code. Just give me a minute please

Comment: @user2864740 here is the code

Comment: Is the speed affected much by the *number* of items?

Comment: yes. Whenever scroling down for other items, my app goes damn slow

Comment: So as long as there are only a few items or no scrolling, then it's fast?

Comment: Yes Sir. No scroll = fast

Comment: Try logging how many times you add an item to lstHolders. Then log how many times you have to iterate through that loop in the runnable.  It's insane.  I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I know I am doing something stupid here but can you give me an alternative way to get the same result without using the handler or looping through it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am really stuck with this problem for a long time. I have to show my app prototype to some of the investors day after tomorrow. Banging my head. Need help

Comment: Add the log statements I'm suggesting and see for yourself.  Like I said, I don't know what your trying to do, but the results of the logging should look suspicious to you